# CSS: Set Max Width of an Image to Its Actual Pixel Width

Tags: html, css

I am playing around with a responsive layout and I am trying to get my image handling to behave a specific way.

I want the `max-width` of my image to never exceed its actual resolution, however if that is too wide for the screen I'd like the width to be 90% of the screen width. The only solution I can come up with for this is set `width: 90%;` and then to hard-code the `max-width` for every image I want to display like this, which is problematic if I want to change the image on the fly or update it frequently.

Is there any CSS I can use to describe this scenario or do I have to rely on javascript tricks to set the `max-width` from the image's actual width once the image has finished loading?

Comment: Show us your CSS rules that you attempted and the HTML structure.

Comment: if you set width for your image to be 100%, your image will always occupy full width of the container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the following may work.  Set the `max-width: 90%` and the let the image take its natural width (`width: auto`, default value).

See the samples below.

There is an end-point (corner case) when the image size is identical to the width of the containing block (screen size).  In this case, the image will take 90% of the width of the parent block.  If you need this to be 100%, you would need jQuery/JavaScript to take care of the exception.

```css
div {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
div img {
  max-width: 90%;
  vertical-align: top; /* Removes white space below baseline */
}
.ex1 {
  width: 500px;
}
.ex2 {
  width: 400px;
}
.ex3 {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ex1">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x100">
</div>
<div class="ex2">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x110">
</div>
<div class="ex3">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x120">
</div>
```

Comment: This worked great, I never thought of tackling it the other way around like that. I can live with the edge case.